# How to fix some errors compile java

Tags: java

I need you to just help me with the following java file

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException; 
import java.security.InvalidKeyException; 
import java.security.Key; 
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; 
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec; 
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException; 
import javax.crypto.Cipher; 
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException; 
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException; 
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec; 
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec; 

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    OtherClass myObject = new OtherClass("pYQ4/pRt1g0EEdMuf8j2hg==", "nFgAIwY", "bkZnQUl3WVF1bXl2ZUpUYg==");
    System.out.print(myObject);
  }
}

public class OtherClass
{
  private String message;
  private boolean answer = false;
  public String OtherClass(str,str2,str3)
  { 
    AlgorithmParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(str3.getBytes())); 
    Key secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(str2.getBytes(), "AES"); 
    Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding"); 
    instance.init(2, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec); 
    return new String(instance.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(str.getBytes()))); 
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return message;
  }
}
```

I have tried with some sites to test java code online and received the following error message: Check class headers... parsing individual files failed!

Comment: Where do you try this code?

Comment: Can you help me with a specific fix?  I just started learning recently

Comment: compilejava(dot)net

Comment: Both are separate class file or not?

Comment: This file is unique

Comment: @Stultuske I am a PHP programmer, I have no intention of officially joining Java

Answer (score 1):

```
OtherClass myObject = new OtherClass("pYQ4/pRt1g0EEdMuf8j2hg==", "nFgAIwY", "bkZnQUl3WVF1bXl2ZUpUYg==");
```

You called the constructor. First you need know about the constructor and method.

**Edit**

```
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec; 
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class SampleCode {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, BadPaddingException, Exception
  {
    SampleCode sampleCode =new SampleCode();
    OtherClass myObject = sampleCode.new OtherClass();
    System.out.print(myObject.OtherClassMethod("pYQ4/pRt1g0EEdMuf8j2hg==", "nFgAIwY", "bkZnQUl3WVF1bXl2ZUpUYg=="));
  }

 public class OtherClass {
    private String message;
    private boolean answer = false;

    public String OtherClassMethod(String str, String str2, String str3) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, Exception,
            BadPaddingException {
        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(str3.getBytes()));
        Key secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(str2.getBytes("UTF-16"), "AES");
        Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
        instance.init(2, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        return new String(instance.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(str.getBytes())));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return message;
    }
  }
}
```

Try this

Comment: @KhảiPhan First you learn about the basic java like method declaration, expression ,exception handling,constructors. Use some IDE like Eclipse. It is helpful to find some little errors

Comment: @JeyaNandhana still won't compile. as to the OP, it is one single file. You have two public classes in one file.

Comment: I used the inner class. It is possible in java

Comment: I see a new error in your code: /tmp/java_HUd7xr/SampleCode.java:20: error: reached end of file while parsing
  }
   ^
/tmp/java_HUd7xr/OtherClass.java:33: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
2 errors

Comment: @KhảiPhan in the answer, the last } is outside the codeblock. probably you forgot that

Comment: Please try it with compilejava(dot)net

Comment: try and read the error method, it says exactly where to problem is. Get the second class out of the first one, and call the constructor correctly, and it'll work

Answer (score 0):

Please learn the Java basics to understand constructors, methods and use IDE's like eclipse or Intellij for java.

Further, Try below. It wont give compilation error:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OtherClass myObject = new OtherClass();
        String myObjectStr= myObject.otherClassMethod("pYQ4/pRt1g0EEdMuf8j2hg==", "nFgAIwY", "bkZnQUl3WVF1bXl2ZUpUYg" +
                "==");
        System.out.print(myObjectStr);
    }
}

 class OtherClass
{
    private String message;
    private boolean answer = false;

    public String otherClassMethod(String str,String str2,String str3)
    {
        try {
            AlgorithmParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(str3.getBytes()));
            Key secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(str2.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
            instance.init(2, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            return new String(instance.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(str.getBytes())));
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return null;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, its work. Is the base64 decoding in this way correct?

Comment: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 7 bytes

Comment: You just add " UTC-16".. @KhảiPhan Ex:     Key secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(str2.getBytes("UTF-16"), "AES");